# On Click add HTML Elements

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am stuck with jquery wherein I am trying to add dynamic html elements (on click of +) which should also get removed on clicking on (-).
Each element should have unique name and id say "name_1","name_2"...

But it doesn't seem to going my way.

Here is my code:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  var maxField = 10;
  var addButton = $('.add_button');
  var wrapper = $('.field_wrapper');
  var fieldHTML = $('.field_wrapper1').html();
  var x = 1;
  $('.add_button').click(function() {
    if (x < maxField) {
      x++;
      $('.field_wrapper').append('<div class="field_wrapper1" style = "display:none;margin:20px;"><div><strong>*Upload New Contract Copy :</strong><input type="text" name="text_1" id = "text_1" value="" maxlength="50"/><strong><font color="#ff0000">* </font>Upload New Contract Copy :</strong><input type="file" name="pdf_1" id="pdf_1" accept="application/pdf" /><a href="javascript:void(0);" class="remove_button" title="Remove field"><img src="http://www.allintravellocal.com/images/minus_img.jpg"/></a><label for="contract_copy_pdf" class="err" id="err_lbl_contract_copy_pdf"></label></div></div>');
    }
  });
  $(wrapper).delegate('.remove_button', 'click', function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $(this).parent('div').remove();
    x--;
  });
});
```

```html
<div class="field_wrapper">
  <div>
    <strong><font color='#ff0000'>* </font>Upload New Contract Copy :</strong>
    <input type="text" name="contract_copy_text_1" id="contract_copy_text_1" value="" maxlength="50" />
    <strong><font color='#ff0000'>* </font>Upload New Contract Copy :</strong>
    <input type="file" name="contract_copy_pdf_1" id="contract_copy_pdf_1" accept="application/pdf" />&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;(*.pdf)
    <a href="javascript:void(0);" class="add_button" title="Add field">
      <img src="http://www.allintravellocal.com/images/plus_img.jpg" />
    </a>
    <label for="contract_copy_pdf" class="err" id="err_lbl_contract_copy_pdf"></label>
  </div>
</div>
```

Here is my fiddle :

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/hLtqe0d8/1/)

Comment: You will not see the inserted div if you have a display:none property when you insert it. Also, avoid using <a> for items that not are anchors. Use <button>.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Its working as expected but with few things to modify:

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/Guruprasad_Rao/hLtqe0d8/8/)**

- > **You have set `display:none` to your added element and even though its
  >   getting appended its not getting shown in the `UI`. So just remove
  >   that property as below**:

`$('.field_wrapper').append('<div class="field_wrapper1" style = "margin:20px;">... }`

- > **Use `.on` instead of `.delegate` if you are using `jquery.js` > `1.7` because As of jQuery 1.7, `.delegate()` has been superseded by
  >   the `.on()` method according to [this](http://api.jquery.com/delegate/)
  >   and so the below code changes**

**Changes**

```
$(wrapper).on('click','.remove_button', function(e){ 
     e.preventDefault();
     $(this).parent('div').remove();
     x--;
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Why you have this `display:none` inside field_wrapper1:

```
<div class="field_wrapper1" style = "display:none;margin:20px;">
```

You will never see the newly created element unless change to `display:block`.
And for the increment unique name and id:
Place `x++;` after appended function like so:

```
  $('.field_wrapper').append('<div class="field_wrapper1" style = "display:block;margin:20px;"><div><strong>*Upload New Contract Copy :</strong><input type="text" name="text_'+x+'" id = "text_'+x+'" value="" maxlength="50"/><strong><font color="#ff0000">* </font>Upload New Contract Copy :</strong><input type="file" name="pdf_1" id="pdf_1" accept="application/pdf" /><a href="javascript:void(0);" class="remove_button" title="Remove field">-</a><label for="contract_copy_pdf" class="err" id="err_lbl_contract_copy_pdf"></label></div></div>'); 
        x++;
```

Answer (score 1):

Check this [Js Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/hLtqe0d8/9/) link, and each elements have unique id and name as you need.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
var maxField = 10;
var addButton = $('.add_button');
var wrapper = $('.field_wrapper');
var fieldHTML = $('.field_wrapper1').html();
var x = 1;
$('.add_button').click(function(){
    if(x < maxField){
        x++;
        id='text_'+x;
        name="name_"+x;
        $('.field_wrapper').append('<div class="field_wrapper1" style = "display:block;margin:20px;"><div><strong>*Upload New Contract Copy :</strong><input type="text" name='+name+' id ='+ id+' value="" maxlength="50"/><strong><font color="#ff0000">* </font>Upload New Contract Copy :</strong><input type="file" name="pdf_1" id="pdf_1" accept="application/pdf" /><a href="javascript:void(0);" class="remove_button" title="Remove field"><img src="http://www.allintravellocal.com/images/minus_img.jpg"/></a><label for="contract_copy_pdf" class="err" id="err_lbl_contract_copy_pdf"></label></div></div>'); 
    }
});
$(wrapper).delegate('.remove_button','click', function(e){ 
    e.preventDefault();
    $(this).parent('div').remove();
    x--;
});
});
```